# NAE SAT reduction to weighted MAX CUT

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

I am trying to reduce NOT-ALL-EQUAL SAT to MAX-CUT with weighted edges.

I know that if there are weights to the edges, then I can reduce NOT-ALL-EQUAL SAT to MAX CUT by have a $G$ with $2n$ nodes ($x_i$ and $\bar{x}_i$) and edges between the nodes based on each clause. And, adding edges between $x_i$ and $\bar{x}_i$, so on.
But, I am not sure how to assign weights if I have to reduce a NOT-ALL-EQUAL SAT to weighted MAX CUT.

How should I go about this problem?

Comment: btw why can't you reduce unweighted MAX CUT to weighted MAX CUT ?

Comment: I don't remember well the reduction from NAE-SAT to unweighted MAX CUT, but why can't you use the same reduction from NAE SAT to weighted MAX-CUT with all edges having weight 1 ?

Comment: @Suresh, hmmm how would I assign weights if I have to reduce unweighted MAX CUT to weighted MAX CUT?

Comment: well all weights are 1, as @Vor says

Answer (score 1):

NAE-SAT is clearly in NP, while MAX-CUT is NP-complete. So by the definition of NP-complete, there is some reduction from NAE-SAT to MAX-CUT.